# Slope of a plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, curve

I have a curve given by:

```
 M=1001;
    
    mep=1.0050;
    
    y=linspace(-1,0,M);
    
   x=linspace(1,5,M);
    inx=mep./x;
   dinx=.343707;
    idinx= find(inx > dinx,1);
    sl    = gradient(y,x);
    
    s1_po = sl(idinx)
    
    plot(inx,y)
```

The answer I got is sl_po=.25

But when I calculate using the mathematical formula,

If we calculate the slope mathematically at a point, then

[image: s]

From the plot I took two points, but that slope is not matching with what I got from MATLAB
[image: ss]

Am I calculating in the wrong way.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do here. What curve are you looking to find the gradient of? Note that you use `linspace` to create `y`, so it will necessarily be linear (if you try `figure; plot(x, y)` you will see that you get a straight line). And note that you are using `gradient(y, x)` which basically gives you a constant value of 0.25 (try `figure; plot(x, gradient(y, x))`, which is correct.

Comment: If instead you want the gradient of `inx`, I think you have just made a typo, and should be using `gradient(inx, x)` - which does appear to give you the correct gradient of your curve (and note that this is negative). I'm not sure where your second example comes from - and if you want the gradient of `inx`, it should definitely be negative!

Comment: Also note that you've obfuscated your code; your variable is `s1_po`, i.e. with a numreal `1`, whereas in your text you mention `sl_po`, with lowercase L.